# Add Title To Each Bubble in Packed Bubble Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a packed bubble chart that works great. I would like to add a title to each of the larger, separated bubbles. The title should always show and I would like it to be the name of the series. I'm using a split series.

The 'name' attribute shows up in the tooltip, but I would like it to always be displayed.

Here is the code to create the bubbles:

```
Highcharts.chart('bubble-split-chart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'packedbubble',
    animation: false,
    backgroundColor: {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
      stops: [
          [0, '#15191b'],
          [1, '#15191b']
      ]
    },
  },
  // remove hamburger button
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  // remove chart watermark (highcharts.com)
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
  text: '',
  enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      minSize: '1%',
      maxSize: '100%',
      zMin: 1,
      zMax: 400,
      layoutAlgorithm: {
        enableSimulation: false,
        gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
        splitSeries: true,
        seriesInteraction: false,
        dragBetweenSeries: false,
        parentNodeLimit: true
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Test',
    data: [{
      name: "Lorem",
      value: 29.4,
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      name: "Ipsum",
      value: 34.1,
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      name: "Dolor",
      value: 7.1,
      color: 'green'
    }],
  }, {
    name: 'Test 2',
    data: [{
      name: 'Lorem',
      value: 300.1,
      color: 'red'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'Ipsum',
      value: 20.7,
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      name: "Dolor",
      value: 97.2,
      color: 'green'
    }],
  }, {
    name: 'Test 3',
    data: [{
      name: "Lorem",
      value: 8.2,
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      name: "Ipsum",
      value: 9.2,
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      name: "Dolor",
      value: 13.1,
      color: 'green'
    }],
  }]
});
```

Is this possible? Also, if this is possible, how can I remove the name from the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the labels by using `annotations` or `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class.

To remove the series name from tooltip set:

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4771/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should've mentioned that my series has multiple data points in the series array. I've updated my code to reflect that. I tried adding annotations to each data array in the series, but that didn't work. How can I add titles to each series?

Comment: Hi @hashrocket, What is the exact problem with annotations? You can add multiple annotations: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4774/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The problem I'm having with the annotations is they are not tied to the data in the series. I have to place each one separately (and create one for every piece of data in the series) and if the bubbles move, the annotation will not be in the correct place. Is there a way to tie the annotation directly to the name attribute of each data set in the series and place it directly in the center of each of the black bubbles? If you look at the second image, you can see what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I thought that you have a static chart because of disabled animtaion. So, is the problem about responsive? If yes, you need to reposition the annotaions in some event callback function, for example: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

Comment: Sorry about that. I disabled the animation because it was taking quite a long time to stop. And I apologize for so many questions. I'm a Ruby developer, not a JavaScript developer. The problem isn't about responsive, necessarily. I'm just looking for a way to have the name attribute, which is currently in the tooltip, in the center of each of the black bubbles. This way, when someone looks at each black bubble, they can see what company the bubble belongs to, rather than having to hover over each of the inner bubbles.

Comment: No problem, that's what SO is for. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4777/ I have added the labels by using `renderer` metohd and position them on every chart render.

Comment: you can use `{plotOptions: {packedbubble: {dataLabels: {enabled: true}}}}`. it shows the value in the middle of each bubble.